# Is it possible to access files outside the var/www/ folder?

Tags: php, connection

I am trying to connect to a raspberry pi using its IP address and I want to download a file outside its var/www/ folder. The file outside the var/www/ folder is shown through this line of code.

```
    <?php
    foreach (glob("../../home/pi/cc/data/backup/*.txt") as $filename) {
    $filename1 = str_replace(".", "", $filename);
    $filename2 = str_replace("/", "", $filename1);
    $filename3 = str_replace("txt", "", $filename2);
    $filename4 = str_replace("backup", "", $filename3);
    echo "<a href='./$filename' download>".$filename4."</a> <br>";
    }
    ?>
```

When I try to connect to it, it shows a "File Not Found" error.

Btw, I am using XAMPP in a Windows 10 laptop.

Comment: from the web, no. from a script(php) yes

Comment: make sure the `apache` has read access to that file

Comment: @NishanthMatha the apache of the raspberry pi or the apache of my laptop?

Comment: `apache` of where the file is actually stored (where your script looking for)